# How to create a Dataframe from Dictionary where the key and values are all columns?

Tags: python, dictionary, dataframe

Example of dictionary:

```
{'892420643555336193': (8374, 38224),

 '892177421306343426': (6181, 32765),

 '891815181378084864': (4091, 24675),

 '891689557279858688': (8512, 41548),

 '891327558926688256': (9219, 39740)}
```

I want a dataframe where (example of first row)

```
Column A

892420643555336193

Column B

8374

Column C

38224
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dataframe of your dictionary keys, and one of your dictionary values, and use `pd.concat` to combine them:

```
import pandas as pd
# where d is your dictionary
df = pd.concat((pd.DataFrame(list(d.keys())),pd.DataFrame(list(d.values()))),axis=1)

>>> df
                    0     0      1
0  892420643555336193  8374  38224
1  892177421306343426  6181  32765
2  891815181378084864  4091  24675
3  891689557279858688  8512  41548
4  891327558926688256  9219  39740
```

Alternatively, create a normal dataframe with your dictionary, transpose it, and reset the index (note the ordering is switched):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d).T.reset_index()
>>> df
                index     0      1
0  891327558926688256  9219  39740
1  891689557279858688  8512  41548
2  891815181378084864  4091  24675
3  892177421306343426  6181  32765
4  892420643555336193  8374  38224
```

You can then rename your columns as you wish:

```
df.columns = ['A','B','C']
```